# Can I write eslint rule for package.json?

Tags: json, package, eslint, package.json

can I write **ESLint rule for package.json**? To check specific field or can I make it through the plugin? Can't found this information in Google, so hope you'll be tolerate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it with writing custom eslint-plugin. [eslint-plugin-json](https://github.com/azeemba/eslint-plugin-json#readme)  was taken as basis.